# Number base conversion from decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: c#

In the code below can someone make me understand how does the code print the output in letters. Which part of the code converts the numbers to letters? If I input 999 it will convert it to 3E7.

```
class program
 {
   public static void Main()
   {
    int decimalNumber, quotient;
    int i = 1, j, temp = 0;
    char[] hexadecimalNumber = new char[100];
    char temp1;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Decimal Number :");
    decimalNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    quotient = decimalNumber;
    while (quotient != 0)
    {
        temp = quotient % 16;
        if (temp < 10)
            temp = temp + 48;
        else
            temp = temp + 55;
        temp1 = Convert.ToChar(temp);
        hexadecimalNumber[i++] = temp1;
        quotient = quotient / 16;
    }
    Console.Write("Equivalent HexaDecimal Number is ");
    for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)
        Console.Write(hexadecimalNumber[j]);
    Console.Read();

  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like some time spent with the debugger should provide some clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the character values are calculated:

```
if (temp < 10)
    temp = temp + 48;
else
    temp = temp + 55;
```

48 is ASCII code for digit '0', 55 is ASCII code for 'A'.

```
48 + 0 == '0'
48 + 1 == '1'
...
48 + 9 == '9'

55 + 10 + 0 == 'A'
55 + 10 + 1 == 'B'
...
```

Comment: I didn't have a clue about that. Thank you so much. I was using switch statement to convert it from numbers to letters.

Comment: I find it more readable to use `temp = temp + 'A';` instead of the numeric value if you would want to do something like this in your own code.

Comment: @Ralvarez See http://www.asciitable.com/. Please note that 'A' is 65, not 55. 55 is used in the code since we have "extra 10" for letters.

Comment: +1. If the remainder of the previous division operation (modulo operator) is `0` through `9`, the code produces the decimal value that corresponds to the equivalent printable characters `'0'` thru `'9'`. Otherwise, the remainder of the division is in the range `10` thru `15`, and the corresponding printable characters would be `'A'` thru `'F'` (decimal values for those characters are `65` thru `70`. It's the `Convert.ToChar` that evaluates the decimal value and returns a printable character, which is appended to the character array.

Comment: @Herman Using 'A' is more readable, but I guess it should be `temp = temp - 10 + 'A'` instead of `temp = temp + 'A'`.

Comment: @AlexD: you are correct. Should have use `temp = temp + '0';` for my example :)